# How to see if script was sucessfully run in bash script

Tags: bash

i have this code in my script :

```
check() {

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
    DATA=`date +%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S`
        echo "O script $DATA Executou com sucesso" >>$log

        else
    DATA=`date +%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S`
        echo "O script $DATA Executou com erro"; >>$log
        fi
    }
```

but i want to put it in another script and when i execute in crontab once every 15 minutes. I want to check if the script executed successfully or not.

My question is in this first `if` section, how can I put the script `ex3.sh` for example

```
 if script ex3.sh sucess  
      then
            DATA=`date +%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S`
                echo "O script $DATA Executou com sucesso" >>$log
     else
        DATA=`date +%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S`
            echo "O script $DATA Executou com erro"; >>$log
            fi
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is a little confusing.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to check if a certain script execution was successful or not in Bash?

Comment: yes, and i didn't no , i just know how to see if a function are success or not

Comment: I voted to close this question, because the OP until now, despite being asked several times, refuses to provide an exact definition of this problem.

Comment: i didnt know how do define more.. i'm new...

Answer (score 2):

First to the terminology: What you show in your example (`check`) is not a script, but a function. It becomes a script, if you would add an actual invocation to `check`.

But to your proper question: You need to define somehow to the caller, whether or not you are successful. This can be done by havin your function return an exit code. This is done using the `return` statement. The convention is tor return 0 for success, and something between 1 and 127 for failure.

Hence, if you detect an error, do a

```
return 1
```

in your script. If everything goes well, exit it by

```
return 0
```

If you keep to this convention, you can indeed make use of the `if` statement you had in mind:

```
if check ARGUMENTS
then
  .... # check function successful
else
  .... # check function not successful
fi
```

The same principle does not only apply to functions, but also to scripts, with the main difference that with scripts, you signal the exit code not with `return`, but with an `exit` statement, i.e.

```
exit 0 # Success

exit 1 # Failure
```

Comment: yes i know that, but i want to write a script with this..
but my problem is the first if, how can i check if another script, like : ex3.sh run ...
i do this check in my main script, but he only check the function before... not the entire script..

Comment: When you design a piece of program - be it a whole program (script) or a single function -, you also design how an error condition is reported back to the caller. It does not make sense to ask for an arbitrary piece of code, whether it is successful or not, because the concept of what exactly does _success_ mean, needs to be defined first.

Comment: yes i understand, but in this exercise, i just want to put in another script , if the first script run with sucess or not... 
in m code i put in the same script, but  i want to create another and call the first script to see if runs all

Comment: You still have not defined, what "success" means.

Comment: `only check the function before... not the entire script.` do you mean you need to check the validity of a script before running it?

Comment: @chamilad : Good point, but even then, we need to define what "validity" means. Syntactic correctness?

Comment: i have to check the entire script . the script i will have 2/3 functions, but my problem is to do other script to see if the main script are running with sucess or not

Comment: How do you know what success is? Some people might already consider success if the script does not accidentally reformat their hard disk. Unless you specify your question in a precise way, I don't think we can help you here.

Comment: my sucess is if script do the functions normally, so, in echo$? = 0 i guess,

Comment: What is a _normal_ vs. an _abnormal_ way to perform a function? Since you are refer to `$?`, this is the exit code, so you **define success** as having exit code zero. You should have said this in the first place, and I suggest that you update your question with this infomation. But, this is exactly the approach that I discussed in my answer to your question.

Comment: sorry , i'm new in bash, i didn't understand well, can u explain if u want? regards

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash. Just with plain logical thinking. You have some program P - it does not matter whether this is a bash script or a bash function or what ever. You want run it, and then detect, whether it was running **successfully**. Now, 'successfully' is an English word, which has - as every word - no precise meaning unless you define it. It is pointless to discuss an issue, where you do not provide an exact definition of your goal.